# Can anyone please explain to me what is wrong with the following code

Tags: python

```
def search(num_list, find):
    while True:
        if not num_list:
            return "Not in list"
        else:
            i = int(len(num_list) // 2)
            if int(num_list[i]) == find:
                return i
            elif int(num_list[i]) > find:
                num_list = (lambda x: x < num_list[i], num_list)
            elif int(num_list[i]) < find:
                num_list = (lambda x: x > num_list[i], num_list)


checkList = [2, 5, 8, 18, 22, 35, 45, 72]
element = int(input("Enter number to be found: "))
print(search(checkList, element))
```

The following error message occurs when i try to run it with any number:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahul/PycharmProjects/binSearch/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(search(checkList, element))
  File "/home/rahul/PycharmProjects/binSearch/main.py", line 7, in search
    if int(num_list[i]) == find:
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

So I am trying to make a python binary search algorithm for class and thought this would work fine. I have no idea why this is not working and would love an expert opinion

Comment: Your `num_list` is a list, but should be string, if you want to call `int()`.

Comment: I think you're trying to **filter** your list, but you're just creating a tuple of two elements: `num_list = (lambda x: x < num_list[i], num_list)`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear...int() argument must be ... not 'list'

Comment: `num_list = (lambda x: x < num_list[i], num_list)` This reassigns `num_list` so it isn't a list anymore.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Chrissu Yes, the message is clear, but he wants to know _why_ it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The **reason** you are getting this error, is your lambda function is in a tuple of a function and a list. So just looking at that part:

```
num_list = [2, 5, 8, 18, 22, 35, 45, 72]
i = 5
num_list = (lambda x: x < num_list[i], num_list)

print(num_list)
```

result:

```
(<function <lambda> at 0x107a170e0>, [2, 5, 8, 18, 22, 35, 45, 72])
```

which is the memory address of the lambda function, and a list, which you end up passing to `int()`, giving the error that you see.